# Why can't nativescript-geolocation resolve when building an APK for release?

Tags: android, nativescript

I am using Svelte Native, which is an offshoot of NativeScript.  One of the libraries that I've imported has been nativescript-geolocation.

**I've done this like so:**  `import * as geolocation from "nativescript-geolocation";`

This works fine when I do a cloud build and test out on my phone using `tns preview`

When I try and build an APK using `tns cloud build android` it cannot resolve the nativescript-geolocation dependency.

**I get the following error:**

```
ERROR in ./App.svelte
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nativescript-geolocation' in '/home/arthur/todoapp/app'
 @ ./App.svelte 14:0-56 68:1-34 72:1-26
 @ ./app.ts
```

How can I get native-script geolocation to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your build is missing the `nativescript-geolocation` dependency.

Running `tns plugin add nativescript-geolocation` should add it to `package.json` and fix the build.

I believe the reason it works in the preview version is that the Preview app has the geolocation plugin pre-installed.